# Fluent assertion Should().ThrowExactlyAsync should fail for derived types, but it doesn't

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

The following `Func` delegate throws an `ArgumentNullException`:

```
Func<Task> act = async () => await _someService
            .someMethod(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Using [Fluent assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/), the assertion:

```
act.Should().ThrowExactlyAsync<ArgumentException>();
```

Should fail:

> *Asserts that the current `Func` throws an exception of the exact type `TException` (and not a derived exception type).*

`ArgumentNullException` derives from `ArgumentException`, given the description, the assertion should fail, but it passes.

Is it a bug or am I misusing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `ThrowExactlyAsync` returns a `Task`, you're not actually doing anything unless you `await` it:

```
await act.Should().ThrowExactlyAsync<ArgumentException>();
```

Comment: On further checks I found that `act` is `System.Func'1[[System.Threading.Tasks.Task, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...]]` how is this the same as an `ArgumentException`? I mean, how can it pass the test? Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: It passes because no test/assertion is actually being executed. It's a Task, basically a promise to run the assertion. BTW thanks for the accept, that put me over 100k rep finally haha

Comment: I see, makes sense. Well, it's the correct answer, so, you have no one but yourself to blame for this :D I'm glad I was the one to push you through, though. 

Answer (score 1):

Replace `act.Should().ThrowExactlyAsync<ArgumentException>();`
with `await act.Should().ThrowExactlyAsync<ArgumentException>();`\

This will give you a correct result (fail in this case).

Comment: So, exactly what I wrote 5 minutes ago?

Comment: Yes, I posted after you wrote it - missed on "one new answer" link.